# is this too much refactoring?

Tags: java, refactoring

I try to refactor a code so that it will use separate methods to do some calculations. Just to make it clear.

What I want to know is, **is it a good practice or a bad one to write a separate method to find out a simple thing like a number is odd or even** **?**

The original code is ,

```
    int n = 11;
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Not selected");
    } else {
        boolean isPrime = true;
        if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
            isPrime = false;
        } else {
            int i = 2;
            double a = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(n));
            while (i <= a) {
                if (n % i == 0) {
                    isPrime = false;
                }
                ++i;
            }
        } 
        if(isPrime){
            System.out.println("Prime it is");
        }
    }
```

The refactored code is,

```
    int n = 11;
    if (isEven(n)) {
        System.out.println("Not selected");
    } else { 
        if (isPrime(n)) {
            System.out.println("Prime it is");
        }
    }

public static boolean isEven(int n) {
    return n % 2 == 0 ? true : false;
}

public static boolean isPrime(int n){
    if(n==0 || n==1)return false;        
    int i=2;
    double a = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(n));
    while(i<=a){
        if(n%i==0){
            return false;
        }            
        ++i;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Just a tip: `n % 2 == 0 ? true : false` is exactly equivalent to `n % 2 == 0`.

Comment: Its a good practice... even if it is for finding an even or odd number

Comment: for the above code, instead of the isEven method, you could just use the if(n % 2 ==0) check as premature optimization of that condition would not be required at this point

Comment: I prefer seeing the isEven() method. This does not fall into the premature optimisation trap. Quite the contrary. BTW the just in time compiler will inline this method if this code is warm. Generally speaking the JIT works better with shorter methods.

Comment: Code is much more readable after your refactoring. In addition to removing the ternary operator and directly returning `n % 2 == 0`,  you can also collapse `if (isPrime(n))` into the surrounding else, like this: `} else if (isPrime(n)) {`. This code will have the same indentation as the then clause and will improve a bit more readability.

Answer (score 8):

It's generally considered good practice to break code down into separate methods for things like readability, length, or cyclomatic complexity, especially if you are not changing how the code works.

Boolean expressions, like what you have extracted, are often good choices for a quick extract function refactor. It allows a reader of the code base to know why a boolean expression is important or what it does by being able to read a descriptive function name versus complex domain related boolean math which they may not care to know the intricate details of.

A good book about commonly considered best practices in Java for code organization is a book called [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882). It's a pretty easy and enjoyable read, I would suggest it.

Comment: I agree. Breaking bigger methods into more shorter ones tends to be a good idea, since shorter methods are also easier to name, read and test. Of course, the best basis for a refactoring is a well written unit test, so you can sure your refactoring doesn't change the behavior.

Answer (score 4):

This is referred to as functional decomposition, and (in my opinion) is always good practice.

Not only is it easier to read, you can find problems in that code easier, since you can now easily test each section individually.

For example, you can now make sure `isEven` actually returns an even number. If a problem arises later on, you know that method is not the issue. This is called [unit testing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing).

---

I suggest switching

```
if(isEven(n)) {

} else {
    if(isPrime(n)) {

    }
}
```

to

```
if(isEven(n)) {

} else if(isPrime(n)) {

}
```

Since it gives the same functionality, yet saves you a line.

Although, if you were counting `0` as being even, you wouldn't even need `isPrime`; if it's not even, it has to be prime. You wouldn't need to perform all the processing in `isPrime`:

```
if(isEven(n)) {
    System.out.println("Even");
} else {
    System.out.println("Odd");
}
```

To make it a bit cleaner:

```
String result = isEven(n) ? "Even" : "Odd";
System.out.println(result);
```